# Restore deleted user using Google Admin API

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I deleted a user before and was able to recover them by following https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/undelete. Through research, I saw that they can also be recovered through the admin console making it a lot easier.

The problem is that I can't find the user I deleted recently on both of them. Any suggestions on how I can fix this problem, or if I can still do that?

I would be grateful for any help. Thank you in advance.